# Null references to widgets in Custom dialog Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I'm trying to do my custom Dialog,

So I did the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_newpassord"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/activity_login_field_password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_title"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_newpassord2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_newPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_newpassord"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_ko"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/dialog_button_ok"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_newpassord2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_newpassord2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_alert"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_newpassord2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

then in the activity I have:

```
private void newPasswordDialog(){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
        dialog.setTitle("New password");

        final EditText password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_newpassord);
        final EditText password2 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_newpassord2);
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ko);
        Button accept = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ok);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isEmptyEditText(password) || isEmptyEditText(password2))
                {
                    //Lanzar visibility y meter texto
                }
                else
                {
                    //comprobar que son iguales los passwords
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

But when I launch the app, and call the newPasswordDialog, all the references to widgets are set to null, and obviously when arrives to `cancel.onClic{..}` it crash

How can I avoid this null references?

Comment: the problem is with your ctx. Where are you calling this Dialog.Activity or Adapter or Fragment?

Comment: Calling from  Activity. `this.ctx = this;`

Comment: try the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
private void newPasswordDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new   
  AlertDialog.Builder(yourClass.this);//Activity.this
   View v=getLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,null);
     dialog.setView(v);
    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
    dialog.setTitle("New password");

    final EditText password = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_newpassord);
    final EditText password2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_newpassord2);
    Button cancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ko);
    Button accept = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ok);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isEmptyEditText(password) || isEmptyEditText(password2))
            {
                //Lanzar visibility y meter texto
            }
            else
            {
                //comprobar que son iguales los passwords
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog d=dialog.create();
    d.show();

   }
```

Comment: Changed, but, still returning null on widgets. I changed to: `dialog.findViewById(...)` to `v.findViewById(...)` because AS was "warning" that could not be possible in dialog. Even that changes, are not returning the reference.

Comment: `getLayoutInflator.inflate` is this even valid? o.O 
Make sure you're inflating the correct layout file @Shudy

Comment: ooooouuuu fffuuuu........ Do you know that feeling when you are to many time in the same code/layout, etc.. and your brain always tricks you about this little things? as @PedroOliveira said.. the layout was not the correct one. Thanks -Rushi worked perfect know. P.D: need to sleep